# Why don't I get SSID from scanResults and how do I get it?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am writing a code to scan for all the available Wifi networks on my android. After scanning I want to display the SSID and if the network is open/wep/wpa/wpa2 secured. My coed for doing this is as follows:

```
private ListView lv;
List<ScanResult> scanList;
private void getWifiNetworksList(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
               // sb = new StringBuilder();
                scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                sb.append("\nNumber of Wifi Connections: " + scanList.size() + "\n\n");
                for(int i = 0; i < scanList.size(); i++){
                    SSIDList.add(scanList.get(i).SSID + "\n" + scanList.get(i).capabilities);
                }
                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listlayout, R.id.listTextView, SSIDList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);                
        }, filter);
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }
```

However, in my scan results I don't get any SSIDs. I am able to see the capabilities though. I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone please tell what's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: i don't see closing bracket for `onReceive`, did you put it?

Comment: regarding the question, probably the reason is the network being hidden

Comment: Na, I see a bunch of capabilities but no SSIDs.

Comment: that's what i mean, probably for hidden network the capabilities do show up but ssid does not

Comment: Ok would agree to that. But when I scan manually (using Android's Wifi i.e. from Settings) I see some WiFi's which are not hidden.